# Flutter youtube_player_flutter: ^7.0.0+6 full Screen

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am using  this plugin `youtube_player_flutter: ^7.0.0+6` for playing youtube video. The problem is that when I try to play the video in full screen landscape the video playing but gets cut from edges and covers the whole screen in landscape
[image]

here you can video is not covering full height and width

my code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:youtube_player_flutter/youtube_player_flutter.dart';

class video extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _videoState createState() => _videoState();
}

class _videoState extends State<video> {
  String videoURL = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oxsBSCf5-B8&list=RDoxsBSCf5-B8&start_radio=1";

  YoutubePlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {

    _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
        initialVideoId: YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(videoURL)
    );

    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            child:Column(
              crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                YoutubePlayerBuilder(
                  player: YoutubePlayer(
                    controller: _controller,
                    aspectRatio:16/9,

                    showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
                  ),
                builder:(context,player){
                    return Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                     player
                    ],
                    );
                },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),


    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Christopher Moore please tell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If to use `ListView.separated`, you can open the video to fullscreen

```
body: ListView.separated(
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return YoutubePlayer(
        key: ObjectKey(_controllers[index]),
        controller: _controllers[index],
        actionsPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
        bottomActions: [
          CurrentPosition(),
          const SizedBox(width: 10.0),
          ProgressBar(isExpanded: true),
          const SizedBox(width: 10.0),
          RemainingDuration(),
          FullScreenButton(),
        ],
      );
    },
    itemCount: _controllers.length,
    separatorBuilder: (context, _) => const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
  ),
);
```

}

[enter link description here](https://github.com/sarbagyastha/youtube_player_flutter/blob/master/packages/youtube_player_flutter/example/lib/video_list.dart)

Comment: You didin't even test this code, It's only scales video to match listView size. It doesn't open the video to fullscreen.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem just now.
I tried this and it seems to work for full screen. Also added a `OrientationBuilder` for removing the `AppBar` in landscape mode only.\

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: _onWillPop,
    child: OrientationBuilder(builder: 
           (BuildContext context, Orientation orientation) {
      if (orientation == Orientation.landscape) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: youtubeHirarchy(),
        );
      } else {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(widget.title),
          ),
          body: youtubeHirarchy(),
        );
      }
    }),
  );
}

youtubeHierarchy() {
  return Container(
    child: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
        child: YoutubePlayer(
          controller: _controller,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

(onWillPop is there for pausing video when going back)
Seems to have the default menues of youtube behind the actual video. If you come up with a better solution please let me know.

Comment: If you dont know how to use WillPopScreen , you can simple start from OrietaionBuilder();

Answer (score 5):

If  what you want to achieve is

1. Show Video on entire screen (Full-screen)

   [image: Full -screen image]
2. Show video widget on portrait together with other widget

   [image: Portrait]

here is how i fixed it

```
   child: OrientationBuilder(
    
    builder: (context, orientaion) {
     switch(orientaion){
       
       case Orientation.portrait:
        return Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.color,
          appBar: AppBar(
            // title: Text(widget.video.title),
            title: Text(
              "Detail",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
          body: Body);
  
         // TODO: Handle this case.
         break;
       case Orientation.landscape:
        return Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.color,
         
          body: Body());
  
         // TODO: Handle this case.
         break;
     }
     
    }
  ),
```

### Build Body based  the orientation

```
bool fullScreen = false;

YoutubePlayerBuilder _buildBurnerWidgetContent() {
  return YoutubePlayerBuilder(
    onEnterFullScreen: () {
      this.fullScreen = true;
    },
    onExitFullScreen: () {
      this.fullScreen = false;
    },
    player: YoutubePlayer(
      aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
      controller: _youtubecontroller,
      showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
      onReady: () {},
      progressColors: ProgressBarColors(
        playedColor: Colors.amber,
        handleColor: Colors.amberAccent,
      ),
    ),
    builder: (context, player) {
      return Column(
        children: [
          // some widgets
          // player,
          //some other widgets
        ],
      );
    });
```

}

### while building the body with different section i check screen orientation

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _hhState createState() => _hhState();
}

class _hhState extends State<Body> {
  bool fullScreen;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
      Flexible(flex: 5, child: _buildBurnerWidgetContent()),
      !this.fullScreen
          ? Padding(padding: null, child: Text("description"))
          : Container(),
      !this.fullScreen
          ? Padding(padding: null, child: Text("TabView"))
          : Container(),
      !this.fullScreen
          ? Padding(padding: null, child: Text("comments"))
          : Container()
    ]));
  }

  _buildBurnerWidgetContent() {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So i too faced one similar issue like this and the solution is actually in their docs on the pub.dev itself.
You need to add the youtubeplayerbuilder at the top of the widget tree and everything else like scaffold will be returned from it's builder method.
https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEhaa.png)

Comment: It is not working :D

Answer (score 0):

**For FullScreen Support**

If fullscreen support is required, wrap your player with `YoutubePlayerBuilder`

```dart
YoutubePlayerBuilder(
    player: YoutubePlayer(
        controller: _controller,
    ),
    builder: (context, player){
        return Column(
            children: [
                // some widgets
                player,
                //some other widgets
            ],
        );
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try checking the orientation of the device using

`MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.landscape`

and if it is in the landscape you can hide the app bar then

for complete example:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: _onWillPop,
    child: Scaffold(
          appBar: MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.landscape
            ? null
            : AppBar(
            title: Text(App),
          ),
          body: youtube(),
        );
      }
    }),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use YoutubePlayerBuilder like that, note I add it before scaffold can you add it after scaffold actually I don't try that before

```
YoutubePlayerBuilder(
    player: YoutubePlayer(
        controller: _controller,
    ),
    builder: (context, player){
        return Scaffold(
           body: SafeArea(
              child: Column(
                 children: [
                     player,
                     // any widget you want to add
                  ] 
              )
           )
        );
    ),
),
```